# How to copy Sitecore Items from one SXA site to another programmatically?

Tags: sxa

We are using Sitecore SXA with one global website and 6 cloned sites (regional sites). Now, client want to handle all the press releases in global website only (each press release is a separate page) in such a way they need to configure there itself which press releases can be used in regional countries as well. One approach I am thinking is to have a command to copy to regional sites with below steps

1. Get all regional sites list
2. Get all press releases from global site
3. Loop through each country and copy/update press releases specific to each country

Is there any blog similar to this explaining the steps or any other alternative approach (Sitecore Jobs probably) to handle the same?

Thanks

Comment: I would not copy items around. Start by reading https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-content-as-a-delegated-area.html and on delegated areas and start thinking from such a perspective.

Comment: You should try what @Gatogordo suggested. Seems like a great fit for your setup

Comment: But different cloned sites need different press releases. Not all will use the same press releases every time

Comment: And you will only clone the ones which are relevant for that cloned site

Comment: yeah, got your point. Its time for me to convince the client to use this :) Because they want to have some checklist and configure there itself

Comment: If you end up for copy anyway, powershell

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a package containing the press releases and use a module like [Sitecore.Ship](https://github.com/kevinobee/Sitecore.Ship) to transfer and install the package on the desired Sitecore instances using code.

-- EDIT per your comment:

You can setup a [shared datasource](https://doc.sitecore.com/users/sxa/15/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/share-data-sources-and-presentation-using-the-multisite-feature.html), and persist all press releases in there. In each individual site you can make the user select which particular press releases they want to view by e.g. using categories and filter on categories or just let them make a selection from all items in the data source.

Comment: Thanks for the update @Jevgeni. I want to move items from one site to other in the same instance on a particular condition and all at a time

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I've updated my answer :)